# How to reuse a Yew callback for multiple elements

Tags: rust, yew

I want to use the callback onclick for both buttons without creating a clone of it like this:

```
let onclick2 = onclick.clone()
```

I tried using `onclick.clone().emit()` but the 'use of moved value' error still persists with this.

```rust
#[function_component]
pub fn Navbar() -> Html {
    let navigator = use_navigator().unwrap();
    let onclick = Callback::from(move |route: &Route| navigator.push(route));
    html! {
        <nav class="bg-indigo-700 flex justify-between items-center mx-auto max-w p-3">
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-gray-50 font-bold text-2xl">{"Arithmetic Booster"}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="flex space-x-2">
                <button class="text-gray-50 bg-indigo-600 p-2 rounded-md" onclick={ move |_| {onclick.emit(&Route::Home)}}>{"Play"}</button>
                <button class="text-gray-50 bg-indigo-600 p-2 rounded-md" onclick={ move |_| {onclick.emit(&Route::Scores)}}>{"Scores"}</button>
                <button class="text-gray-50 bg-red-600 p-2 rounded-md">{"Quit"}</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can reuse the callback without creating a clone and assigning it to the second button?

Comment: [A `Callback` is just a wrapper for an `Rc`](https://docs.rs/yew/latest/src/yew/callback.rs.html#15-18), so cloning it consists simply in increasing the reference counter. Why don't you want to clone?

Comment: @Jmb I think OP wants to avoid the variable `onclick2` rather than avoid cloning.

Comment: @Jmb, I don't have a problem with using clone, however creating a second variable just for the use of cloning is something I want to avoid, as I'll be using more elements on the same callback.

Comment: FYI Your callback is just extra allocation here and you may as well just call `navigator.push` from within the `onclick` closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a new scope in the closure's declaration, this is a common idiom:

```rust
#[function_component]
pub fn Navbar() -> Html {
    let navigator = use_navigator().unwrap();
    let onclick = Callback::from(move |route: &Route| navigator.push(route));
    html! {
        <nav class="bg-indigo-700 flex justify-between items-center mx-auto max-w p-3">
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-gray-50 font-bold text-2xl">{"Arithmetic Booster"}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="flex space-x-2">
                <button class="text-gray-50 bg-indigo-600 p-2 rounded-md"
                    onclick={
                        let onclick = onclick.clone();
                        move |_| onclick.emit(&Route::Home)
                    }>{"Play"}</button>
                <button class="text-gray-50 bg-indigo-600 p-2 rounded-md"
                    onclick={ move |_| onclick.emit(&Route::Scores) }>{"Scores"}</button>
                <button class="text-gray-50 bg-red-600 p-2 rounded-md">{"Quit"}</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a clear way of doing this.